# Como obter os tickets que ficaram abertos no mês de maio?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou a trabalhar com uma base dados que contém todos os `tickets` registados no [otrs](http://www.otrs.com/) da empresa onde trabalho.

Pretendo fazer uma query onde que devolva todos os tickets que ficaram em aberto no mês de maio.

O problema é que um ticket pode ser aberto e fechado no mesmo dia e se tentar filtrar por todos os tickets abertos entre o dia `2015-05-01 00:00:00` e `2015-05-01 23:59:59`, a query irá devolver os tickets que foram abertos e que já foram fechados.

Estou a trabalhar com as seguintes tabelas

- **ticket_history**
- **ticket_state**
- **ticket_type**
- **ticket_history_type**
- **ticket_state_type**

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
SELECT 
    th.id,
    th.name,
    th.history_type_id,
    th.ticket_id,
    th.type_id,
    th.queue_id,
    th.state_id,
    th.create_time,
    th.change_time

FROM 
    sapec_db.ticket_history as th
    left join ticket_state ts
    on th.state_id=ts.id
    left join ticket_type tt
    on th.type_id=tt.id
WHERE
    th.change_time between '2015-05-01 00:00:00' and '2015-05-31 23:59:59' 
    -- 4 Incident 
    and tt.name like 'Incident'
    -- 1 new 4 open
    and ts.name like 'open' 
group by 
    ticket_id
;
```

Comment: O que define que um ticket foi fechado? Você possui uma data de fechamento em sua tabela?

Comment: Bom dia Pedro, o que define um ticket fechado é  state_id quando um ticket é aberto é criado um registo na tabela ticket_history como ticket aberto se o ticket sofrer alguma alteração sempre registado nessa tabela, e quando é fechado é criado um registo como foi fechado, estado do ticket passa a closed successful na coluna state_id

Comment: Então não é só colocar na sua cláusula `WHERE` para considerar apenas registros que o `state_id` for diferente de `closed`? Algo assim: `AND ts.state_id != closed_id`

Comment: Se ele foi fechado e reaberto então são criadas duas linhas? Se for isso é só setar o where pelo state_id = closed e a data. Existe alguma coluna que dite o estado do ticket como fechado, ou aberto direto pelo id?

Comment: Pedro o problema é que se eu introduzir ela cláusula vai-me dar os tickets que já estiveram em aberto e neste momento estão fechados, porque eu estou a trabalhar com uma tabela que regista todas as alterações dos tickets

Comment: KhaosDoctor na tabela ticket_history estão todos os estados dos tickets um ticket pode ter sido aberto as 10h de hoje e ter sido fechado as 11h existe uma coluna na tabela ticket_history que se chama change_time que regista a data e a hora de cada alteração, sim sempre que há uma alteração é registada. com essa cláusula irá me dar os tickets que foram abertos mas agora estão fechados porque nesse mesmo dia ja estiveram abertos, e eu apenas quero que me dê os tickets que ficarem com o state_id em aberto

Answer (score 1):

Podemos fazer um LEFT com a própria sapec_db.ticket_history, excluindo os ticket_id que tiverem algum registro do tipo closed successful.

Pode por favor verificar como vai se comportar o comando abaixo? 
Precisei manter apenas o ticket_id no SELECT devido a GROUP BY que usou.

```
SELECT
    th.ticket_id
FROM sapec_db.ticket_history AS th
LEFT JOIN ticket_state ts
    ON th.state_id = ts.id
LEFT JOIN ticket_type tt
    ON th.type_id = tt.id
LEFT JOIN sapec_db.ticket_history AS th2
    ON th2.ticket_id = th.ticket_id
LEFT JOIN ticket_state ts2
    ON th2.state_id = ts2.id
    AND ts2.name = 'closed successful'
WHERE th.change_time BETWEEN '2015-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-05-31 23:59:59'
AND tt.name LIKE 'Incident'
AND ts.name LIKE 'open'
AND ts2.id IS NULL
GROUP BY th.ticket_id;
```

Comment: Arranjei outra solução, obrigado a todos mas é impossível extrair os dados correctos através desta maneira.
Criei uma base de dados e importei os csv de cada mês, em vez de fazer querys a uma base bados em produção onde os tickets estão constantemente a mudar de estado.
Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Basta você adicionar na clausula WHERE a condição para ignorar "tickets fechados", pelo o que eu vi nos comentários, você disse que estão fechados quando `state_id = 'closed'` então basta adicionar `state_id != 'closed'` como abaixo:

```
SELECT 
    th.id,
    th.name,
    th.history_type_id,
    th.ticket_id,
    th.type_id,
    th.queue_id,
    th.state_id,
    th.create_time,
    th.change_time

FROM 
    sapec_db.ticket_history as th
    left join ticket_state ts
    on th.state_id=ts.id
    left join ticket_type tt
    on th.type_id=tt.id
WHERE
    th.change_time between '2015-05-01 00:00:00' and '2015-05-31 23:59:59' 
    -- 4 Incident 
    and tt.name like 'Incident'
    -- 1 new 4 open
    and ts.name like 'open' 
    -- remove os tickets fechado
    and state_id != 'closed'
group by 
    ticket_id
;
```

Comment: Edson, se você notar a tabela de estados (pelo nome, em inglês) é ticket_state (ou o alias ts), portanto se não for removida a condição: "and ts.name like 'open'" o seu código não retornará o que você deseja e sim somente os tickets abertos (e que não estejam fechados rsrs)

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seu select precise conter uma subconsulta quando busca o state, tipo...

```
(SELECT LAST(state_id) FROM ticket_history WHERE state_id LIKE 'open' AND id = th.id)
```

Não sei se a sintax está correta, mas de uma pesquisada sobre "subquery" que vc deve achar algo mais preciso.

Talvez esse link te ajude: [Queries correlatas](http://www.devmedia.com.br/subqueries-parte-ii-queries-correlatas/2890)